# calculate signal to noise ratio

Tags: computer-networks

I am trying to calculate a signal to noise ratio to achieve a rate of 300Mbps on a bandwidth of 3Mhz.

The shannon capacity formula `C = B*Log(x,(1+SNR))` should be my friend on this one, but this is my first time doing this calculation.

Currently I am at `300Mbps == 3000000 * Log(2,(1+SNR))` From this point I would just get SNR by its self, but I am not sure how to do it.

My question is: How do I calculate the signal to noise ratio given the speed and bandwidth? I am not sure if the setup of my equation above is correct.

Comment: High-school arithmetics is offtopic here.

Comment: Ah,  so this is the right setup? To finish the problem I just need to finish the arithmetic? I wasn't really asking about the arithmatic. I was having issues finding sources on how to calculate the ratio. I found many sources on what signal to noise is, but very fiew on actually calculating it.

Comment: Then please edit your question to ask the question you're actually having!